# mysql batch update process

Tags: mysql

I need to batch update balances of some users in members table, how should mysql query be?

```
MembersArray = array(1,3,4);
AmountToBeAdded = 10;
```

members

```
id. balance
1.  45
2.  15
3.  0
4.  120
5.  80
```

Thanks already for your help

Comment: Did you have a crack at it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE members SET balance = balance + 10
WHERE members.id IN(1,3,4)
```

Comment: I'm lucky to have discovered this platform, everyone really helps each other and it's a very active platform thank you